# Retrieve file list of an SQL server database which is offline

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have some offline databases on a SQL server. I would like to know which files on disc are related to these databases. Is it possible to retrieve the file list of offline databases without taking them online first?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This will give you a list of all *physical file paths* related to any *offline databases*, along with database name and file type:

```
SELECT
'DB_NAME' = db.name,
'FILE_NAME' = mf.name,
'FILE_TYPE' = mf.type_desc,
'FILE_PATH' = mf.physical_name
FROM
sys.databases db
INNER JOIN sys.master_files mf
ON db.database_id = mf.database_id
WHERE
db.state = 6 -- OFFLINE
```

Answer (score 7):

Or simply

```
select * from sys.databases where state_desc='OFFLINE'
```

Comment: This works, but utilizing `state=6` field/value might be a more concise approach with a faster lookup speed on the TINYINT rather than the NVARCHAR(60).

Comment: @TravisCrooks Do you think this will make any difference in the context we are in here? This is a one-off task, and even if you script it for future use, the _milliseconds_ you _might_ save will not matter. I would even argue that using the descriptive state name is the better choice because no-one will have to go look for what the value _6_ actually means when they come back to this script in the future :-)

Comment: @mikenelson I feel I should downvote your answer because it does not answer the important first part of the OP's question: **Retrieve file list**. On the other hand, it is a helpful partial answer to some, so I won't :-)

Comment: @Oliver Oh yeah I wondered why other people's answers were more long winded! I had only half read the question. But indeed it solves half the problem so still useful.

Answer (score 0):

> **List all the available, but offline SQL server database files**

The following statement will list all the files associated with offline SQL server databases

```
SELECT
    m.physical_name + '\' + m.name AS [file_path]
FROM
    sys.databases AS d 
    INNER JOIN sys.master_files AS m ON d.database_id = m.database_id
WHERE
    d.state_desc = 'OFFLINE'
    --AND m.type_desc = 'ROWS'
GROUP BY
    m.physical_name + '\' + m.name
```

*Note: Uncomment the line `AND m.type_desc = 'ROWS'` (delete the --) to filter the list further to include only database files. Otherwise, log files will also be listed.*

The `GROUP BY` clause is there to prevent entries appearing more than once.

Answer (score 0):

from sql server 2014 on you can you this very useful function: has_dbaccess

```
SELECT name, HAS_DBACCESS(name) FROM sys.databases;
```

that would give you for sure the visibility if you can query the database or not, as ONLINE alone is not enough, as for instance
a database on an availability group synchronizing and healthy is also online but in most cases not accessible.